# Issue in Date Format in JAVA

Tags: simpledateformat

I am using SimpleDateFormat class in JAVA to convert string value to date format.
 Below is the code

```
try{
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date newDate = format.parse(value);
if(newDate != null)
return newDate;
else
return null;
}
```

My input is convertToDate("12-13-2011","dd-MM-yyyy")
 my output is Thu Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2012
 Why it is not throwing an error instead it takes next year and month as JAN.

Thanks
PradeepKumar

Answer (score 2):

You specified a format in which the first two digits are the days and the second two digits are the month.

Anyway, make sure to call

```
format.setLenient(false)
```

if you want a stricter formatting, as without setting this the SimpleDateFormat will try to interpret your date.

Answer (score 0):

("12-13-2011","dd-MM-yyyy") -> because ther is no 13th month? ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's how `SimpleDateFormat` works. If you want to change the behavior extend the class and override the method format to tweak the behavior.